# ReportViewer: Repeat tables on every page

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc, report-viewer2010

I am designing a two page report using the reportviewer control. The second page includes a few textboxes and two tables with different datasets. Both tables have a set amount of rows (25) that can be displayed on one page. Everything works fine when the datasets for both tables returns less than 25 rows, but the issue I am having is if either of the table dataset returns more than 25 rows. In that case a new page should be created replicating everything that is on the second page of the report the (textboxes and the two tables) regardless if only one have data to display or not. Basically every page after the first page should be identical with only the data in the tables changing.

Is there any way to accomplish this using the reportviewer control? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different approaches. I don't know exactly the position of your controls but I think the best solution is include the textboxes in tables header which must be repeated on every page.

Comment: Is there any way to group the two tables together so that they both are included on every page?

Comment: Yes table2 is directly under table 1

Comment: No, in this case I don't think is possible. If Table1 contains 1000 rows it will span on multiple pages and then Table2 will be print. Sorry, I misunderstood your main question: I thought that the only problem were the textboxes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I will have to create a new report for every x number of rows and merge the files together.